# Formating Datetime row to Index row in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime-format

I have a dataset that has the following sample

```
Index     Datetime                       x
 0        1992-01-01 03:00:00            7
 1        1992-01-01 06:00:00            9
 2        1992-01-01 03:00:00            3
```

I would like to convert this into the following format

```
Index                          x
1992-01-01 03:00:00            7
1992-01-01 06:00:00            9
1992-01-01 03:00:00            3
```

I tried following code but did not work

```
dataset.drop(['index'])
```

Any help on this

Comment: `dataset.set_index('Datetime', drop=True, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the Index column first and then try (renaming the Datetime to Index)something like this:

```
df=df.rename(columns = {'Datetime':'Index'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to use your `Datatime` as your index, then you can use the following code:

```
df.set_index(['Datetime'], inplace=True)
```